# Create new and select existing value from a has_many relationship

Tags: activeadmin

Networks contains a has_one relationship for vlans.
Vlans contains a belongs_to relationship for networks.

When I create a new network, I want to have the option of either selecting an existing vlan by vlanid -or- creating a new vlan for the new network.

I have made it as far as being able to create a brand new vlan when I create a network, but I would like to be able to select an existing vlan -or- create a new one.

app/models/network.rb

```
class Network < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :vlan
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vlan, allow_destroy: true
end
```

app/models/vlan.rb

```
class Vlan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :network
end
```

db/migrate/create_network.rb

```
class CreateNetworks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :networks do |t|
      t.string :comment
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

db/migrate/create_vlan.rb

```
class CreateVlans < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :vlans do |t|
      t.string :comment
      t.integer :vlanid
      t.belongs_to :network
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

app/admin/networks.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Network do
  permit_params :comment, :name, vlan_attributes: [ :id, :vlanid, :comment, :_destroy, :_edit ]
  index do
    selectable_column
    column  "Network Name" do |i|
      i.name
    end
    column  :comment
    column "VLAN ID" do |i|
      i.vlan.vlanid
    end
    column "VLAN Comment" do |i|
      i.vlan.comment
    end
    actions
  end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      row  :name
      row  :comment
    end

    panel 'vlan' do
      table_for network.vlan do
        column :vlanid
        column :comment
      end
    end
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Details' do
      f.input :name
      f.input :comment
    end

    f.inputs 'Vlans' do
      f.has_many :vlan do |c|
        c.input :vlanid
        c.input :comment
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

app/admin/vlans.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Vlan do
  belongs_to :network
  permit_params :comment, :vlanid
end
```

I've tried using something like the following in app/admin/networks.rb

```
panel 'vlan' do
  table_for network.vlan do
    column :vlanid, :as => :select
    column :comment
  end
end
```

I do get a drop-down in this instance, but the only values are "Yes" and "No".

This is my first time delving into activeadmin and I'm stumped.
I've seen some similar questions posted around, but none of the answers I've seen seemed to apply to this specific situation.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Existing Vlan will already have network_id, why do you want to select existing vlan?

Comment: The goal is to be able to use the same VLANID across multiple networks to keep the information for the VLAN consistent across multiple networks and multiple sites.

Example: A printer VLAN with VLAN ID 200.  I have fifty sites, all of them need a network associated with the printer VLAN.

Comment: Do I need to flip my associations around so that network belongs_to vlan and vlan has_many networks?

Comment: Yes, `has_one` should be used for only one to one mapping.
When you want to use one to many then you should use `has_many` association.